# How do you close a workbook during BeforeSave event if condition not met?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to close a workbook during the BeforeSave event if a condition is not met. I am using the following code and the save is canceled as expected but the close event crashes excel.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    If X <> Y then
        Cancel = True
        ThisWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
    End If
End Sub
```

I have even tried to call another Sub with the close command in it but that also produces the same issue

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    If X <> Y then
        Cancel = True
        ExitNoSave
    End If
End Sub

Public ExitNoSave ()
    ThisWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
End Sub
```

Here is a screen grab from the code I made a new workbook with only the before save event and it still happens.

[image]

[image]

Does anyone have a way to do this or is it not possible to do this from the BeforeSave event?

Comment: How it crashes Excel? `Excel has stopped Working` ?

Comment: You can call close from `Workbook_BeforeSave`, works fine for me.

Comment: Yeah it says excel stopped working and then gives me the option to debug

Comment: I'm also using excel 2016

Comment: I hate that, I have had already much trouble with it :(

Comment: Do you have more code to share e.g. `Workbook_BeforeClose` - there's nothing obviously wrong the the code you posted so there has to be another factor...

Comment: I updated the question with pictures but I made a blank workbook with only the before save event and it still happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok guys I figured it out you have to use the AfterSave event to accomplish this now apparently so if you cancel the save with the BeforeSave event it passes on that save failed to the AfterSave event you can then write your code for different conditions.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    If 1 <> 2 Then
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_AfterSave(ByVal Success As Boolean)
    If Success = False Then
        ThisWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
    End If
End Sub
```